# Find values of $p$ for which the series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am still having a hard time understanding how to find what values of $p$ allow for the series to converge.

Here is the series I am currently trying to find $p$ for: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1+n^2)^p$$

I tried doing an integral test with $p \gt 0$ but I got a wrong answer I believe.

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: Please check that I formatted it correctly.  You can find a tutorial on formatting on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$ tutorials on the web.  Please do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the integral test consider $\int_{x=1}^{\infty}x(1+x^2)^pdx$. By substitution with $u = 1+x^2$, this is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{u=2}^{\infty}u^pdu$.

$\frac{1}{2}\int_{u=2}^{\infty}u^pdu$ is known to converge $\forall p<-1$, thus the series you provided will converge for all $p<-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) is divergent, *p* must be lesser than $-1$.